# Building a Unix socket bridge via TCP

Tags: networking, tcp, socat, unix-sockets

I have two processes (Client and server) that communicate with each other using a Unix socket `/tmp/tm.ipc`. Both processes (Client and Server) don't support TCP.

Client -> `/tmp/tm.ipc` -> Server

Now, I want to separate both processes to run on two different machines that run in the same subnet. Therefore, I want to build sort of a TCP bridge in between.

Client -> `/tmp/tm-machine1.ipc` -> TCP port 15432 -> `/tmp/tm-tm-machine2.ipc` -> Server

I was thinking to use Socat, but this looks like that it only covers the server listening part.

```
socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:15432,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/tm.ipc
```

Now I want to connect the client's Unix socket to that port. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com) of a sufficient version (OpenSSH 6.7/6.7p1 (2014-10-06) or higher) can do this, if the SSH is initiated from the client to the server system one could write something like

```
ssh -L /path/to/client.sock:/path/to/server.sock serverhost
```

and then the client would connect to `/path/to/client.sock` and the server would listen at `/path/to/server.sock`. You probably will also need to set `-o StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes`, see `ssh_config(5)`.

(And please don't use `/tmp`; improper use of `/tmp` can lead to local security exploits or denials of service or…)

Comment: that is 100% fascinating.  makes you wonder how these features come about, eh? :)