# Using Unix domain socket for different hosts

Tags: unix-sockets

Actually, I have software that runs in the ARM-Linux has three apps of mine.I want to run the one certain application in Linux host x86.

The internal components in my ARM-Linux program communicate using Unix domain socket.

My socket type is: AF_UNIX

I am using old ARM processor doesn't support Valgrind. There is some memory leak in the application that is causing the crash. So I build the application in the host and figuring out how to establish communication between ARM and x86 using domain socket?

---

Now I have a situation where the application `foo` is in ARM and `bar` is Linux x86. Question is it possible to communicate between the different host?

---

I thought Unix domain sockets are inter-domain after reading the below link, I got confused.

I read,

> [UNIX domain sockets are a method by which processes on the same
>   host](https://troydhanson.github.io/network/Unix_domain_sockets.html) can communicate. Communication is bidirectional with stream
>   sockets.
>
> ```
> fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
> ```

Comment: Sockets are, by their very nature, (by themselves) local to one host.

Comment: As a work-around, you can use something as `socat` to divert UNIX sockets over TCP into other machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  You can't communicate across hosts on a network using `AF_UNIX` sockets, as those reference local inodes on the filesystem to bind the socket to, and the local filesystem is only available to the local host.

To communicate between nodes, you'll need to use an `AF_INET` socket, which will bind to an IP address and port, which could be reachable to a different host.

Comment: OK, this clears my confusion. I will add AF_INET socket feature in my application.

Comment: You can however tunnel them over SSH e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420543/building-a-unix-socket-bridge-via-tcp/420548#420548